# (php , mysql) Contact us form mysql injection

Tags: php

I made this anti SQL Injection, I tested if I can still send queries, and it is looks good. could you tell me if you see any problem I missed, before I launch this to the internet? (this is contact us form, no log in)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $email =  $_POST['email'];
    $text =  $_POST['textt'];

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '',  'database1');

    if($name && $email && $text ) {

        echo  "thanks you for contacting us, we will respond within 24 hours.";
    }
    else {
        echo  "Please enter name, email and your message.";

        // echo  $result;
    }

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $name);

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);

    $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $text);


    $query = "INSERT INTO info(username,email,textt) ";
    $query .= "VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$text')";

    mysqli_query($connection, $query);

}

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

For security, bind user supplied values when including them in a query.

Here's what that could look like using mysqli and the information provided
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

```
// renamed `textt` to `text`
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `info` (`username`,`email`,`text`) VALUES (?,?,?);');
$stmt->bind_param($username, $email, $text);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Here's what that would look like using PDO, should that connection be considered.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Perhaps consider renaming your column `textt` to something more descriptive?

Also, normally, you'd want to provide some validation on user supplied input to prevent bots and help prevent user error.

e.g. for the email address:

```
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
} else {
  // often handled with a message or alert funciton
  echo 'Please enter a valid email';
  $error = true;
}
```

e.g. for the username:

```
if(!ctype_space($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
} else {
    // as before often handled by a message/alert function
    echo 'Please provide a valid email address';
    $error = true;
}
```

It's often helpful to store the IP address of the requester. The following can be spoofed, and there are better functions out there, but it is often better than nothing.

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

There are solutions to help ensure it's not a bot completing your form, e.g. reCAPTCHA and honey pots. They're not always appropriate from a UX, UI, security standpoint, but I feel that should be mentioned as well.

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: `trim()` the username before testing its length, not after.

Comment: We'd be better off checking for all whitespace if you want to get technical, updated. And the username suggests a name is already in the database, which could be checked. Or have a format that could be checked with regex. But then again wouldnt they be authenticated by then anyways.